# Using cmake-gui with Qt Creator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I started trying to convert a project to use CMake so that I could import the project into QtCreator to  make use of the QtCreator IDE for this straight C code. This worked pretty nicely as far as giving me auto completions, code diving, etc etc.

I have had a bit of a time getting CMake to build the code as I expected, mostly because it was the first time I have been using it. I recently discovered that there is a cmake-gui that you can point at your source and it will show you the CMake variables and such. What is the proper way to actually use cmake-gui within QtCreator? When I just manually made my CMakelists.txt files within my project, it was enough to get the project in there. Should I just run Cmake-gui using locator and point it to those files? Should I keep the same build directory in cmake-gui that was created from QtCreator? Any tutorial links or guidance apprecaited - didnt find a whole lot googling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I use `cmake-gui` with QtCreator is this:

1. Create a build directory and configure it with `cmake-gui`, like:

   ```
   cmake/project$ mkdir build
   cmake/project$ cd build
   cmake/project/build$ cmake-gui ..
   ```
2. Open the `CMakeLists.txt` file in QtCreator, and set the build path to where you did the configuration:

   [image: QtCreator with CMake-GUI]
3. Let QtCreator run the configuration by clicking "Run CMake", it will use the values you configured with `cmake-gui` in step 1:

   [image: QtCreator with CMake-GUI step 2]
4. You are done :)
5. When you need to reconfigure the CMake build, just fire up the command line, navigate to the build directory and re-run `cmake-gui`.

Comment: For step 3 did you mean "navigate to the source directory" for cmake-gui?

Comment: Step 2 is asking you for the "build" directory containing the CMake configuration and build files - binaries will be also built here. The source directory is the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` and the files it references. You are asking for step 5 now - you have to navigate to the **build** directory to do the configuration.

Comment: You could also add the CMake GUI as an [External Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-external.html#configuring-external-tools) in order to launch it directly from the Qt Creator. You can use the variable `%{CurrentProject:BuildPath}` as argument to open the current project build cache as well.